# How can I make user input name unto UI and not into console in Java?

Tags: java, input, menu, 2d

So, Iam making a 2D GAME for a final project for school and in the main menu I wanted the user to input his name before playing the game but whenever I try to do a scanner the game freezes, or If I try the Jpanel the GUI is kinda infinitely popping up thus making the game unplayable. Anything I can do? BTW Iam only a beginner in java and got this code only on tutorials by RyiSnow. Thank you

I am planning to put the input name part into.

else if (gp.ui.titleScreenState == 3)

[image: input-username-image]

```
package main;


import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;


 public class UI {


     GamePanel gp;
     Graphics2D g2;
     Font arial_40, arial_80B;
     public boolean messageOn = false;
     public String message = "";
     int messageCounter = 0;
     public boolean gameFinished = false;
     public int commandNum = 0;
     public int titleScreenState = 0;
     String playerName = "";

     double playTime;
     DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");


     public UI(GamePanel gp) {
         this.gp = gp;
         arial_40 = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 40);
         arial_80B = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 80);
     }

     public void showMessage(String text) {

         message = text;
         messageOn = true;
     }


     public void draw(Graphics2D g2) {

         this.g2 = g2;

         g2.setFont(arial_40);
         g2.setColor(Color.white);

         //TITLE STATE
         if(gp.gameState == gp.titleState) {
             drawTitleScreen();
         }
         //PLAY STATE
         if (gp.gameState == gp.playState) {
             //latur
         }//PAUSE STATE
         if (gp.gameState == gp.pauseState) {
            drawPauseScreeen();

         }
     }
     public
     void drawTitleScreen(){

         if (titleScreenState == 0){

             g2.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0));
             g2.fillRect(0,0, gp.screenWidth, gp.screenHeight);

             //TITLE NAME
             g2.setFont(g2.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD,96F));
             String text = "Byte Boulevard";
             int x = getXforCenteredText(text);
             int y = gp.tileSize*3;

             //SHADOW
             g2.setColor(Color.gray);
             g2.drawString(text, x+5, y+5);
             //MAIN COLOR
             g2.setColor(Color.white);
             g2.drawString(text, x, y);
         /* IMAGE
         x = gp.screenHeight/2 - (gp.tileSize*2)/2;
         y += gp.tileSize*2;
         g2.drawImage(gp.player.down1, x, y, gp.tileSize*2, gp.tileSize*2, null);
        */

             // MENU
             g2.setFont(g2.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD,48F));

             text = "NEW GAME";
             x = getXforCenteredText(text);
             y += gp.tileSize*2;
             g2.drawString(text, x, y);
             if (commandNum == 0){
                 g2.drawString("►", x-gp.tileSize, y);
             }

             text = "LOAD GAME";
             x = getXforCenteredText(text);
             y += gp.tileSize;
             g2.drawString(text, x, y);
             if (commandNum == 1){
                 g2.drawString("►", x-gp.tileSize, y);
             }

             text = "OPTIONS";
             x = getXforCenteredText(text);
             y += gp.tileSize;
             g2.drawString(text, x, y);
             if (commandNum == 2){
                 g2.drawString("►", x-gp.tileSize, y);
             }

             text = "ABOUT";
             x = getXforCenteredText(text);
             y += gp.tileSize;
             g2.drawString(text, x, y);
             if (commandNum == 3){
                 g2.drawString("►", x-gp.tileSize, y);
             }

             text = "QUIT";
             x = getXforCenteredText(text);
             y += gp.tileSize;
             g2.drawString(text, x, y);
             if (commandNum == 4){
                 g2.drawString("►", x-gp.tileSize, y);
             }
         }
        else if (titleScreenState == 1){

            //intro
            g2.setColor(Color.white);
            g2.setFont(g2.getFont().deriveFont(42F));

            String text = "Welcome! This Game is still under development and ";
             int x = getXforCenteredText(text);
             int y = gp.tileSize*4;
             g2.drawString(text, x, y);

             text = "It is still in its early phase, that's why with utmost respect";
             x = getXforCenteredText(text);
             y += gp.tileSize;
             g2.drawString(text, x, y);

             text = "Please expect little content within the game";
             x = getXforCenteredText(text);
             y += gp.tileSize;
             g2.drawString(text, x, y);

             text = "Press [ENTER] to CONTINUE...";
             x = getXforCenteredText(text);
             y += gp.tileSize*4;
             g2.drawString(text, x, y);

         } else if (titleScreenState == 2) {
             String text = "While our team is currently doing their best in developing";
             int x = getXforCenteredText(text);
             int y = gp.tileSize * 4;
             g2.drawString(text, x, y);

             text = "new contents in to the game, We kindly ask of you";
             x = getXforCenteredText(text);
             y += gp.tileSize;
             g2.drawString(text, x, y);

             text = "to wait in future additions into the game.";
             x = getXforCenteredText(text);
             y += gp.tileSize;
             g2.drawString(text, x, y);

             text = "Enjoy the early phase of our game";
             x = getXforCenteredText(text);
             y += gp.tileSize;
             g2.drawString(text, x, y);

             text = "Press [ENTER] to CONTINUE...";
             x = getXforCenteredText(text);
             y += gp.tileSize * 3;
             g2.drawString(text, x, y);


         }
        else if (gp.ui.titleScreenState == 3){

             String text = "Please input the name of your character: ";
             int x = getXforCenteredText(text);
             int y = gp.tileSize * 4;
             g2.drawString(text, x, y);







         }
     }
     public void drawPauseScreeen (){

         String text = "PAUSED";
         int x = getXforCenteredText(text);
         int y = gp.screenHeight/2;

         g2.drawString(text, x, y);
        //

     }
     public int getXforCenteredText(String text){

         int length = (int) g2.getFontMetrics().getStringBounds(text, g2).getWidth();
         int x = gp.screenWidth/2 - length/2;
         return x;

     }
 }
```

Tried to use scanner but didn't work, tried to use jpanel but didn't work, tried to use bufferedreader but didnt work also

Comment: why would you use Scanner? Every JTextField has a getText() method. What more do you need?

Comment: as stated in my description, Iam a beginner and is not really that familliar with programming. I thought that if using scanner I could get user input. And I got the code only by watching and copying the tutorial from youtube, that is why Iam asking for help

Comment: don't learn from 'Youtube tutorials'. Learn the basics, and see you understand how documentation and basic method calls work before moving to more advanced subjects like GUI's.

Comment: tbh, I have only watched the java basics like sout, scanner, operators, etc. on youtube. But I was appointed as lead programmer in our group in school thats why I had no choice but to watch people tutorial on making a 2d game in youtube.

Comment: this makes no sense at all. why would your school make you do an assignment they haven't taught you the basics (at least) of? Also, parts of your code make no sense, and making about all your variables public is terrible design

Comment: @Stultuske It's a school project. I don't think they will care about variables being public as long as it works.

Comment: @softwareguy any school who doesn't care about that shouldn't be teaching programming.

Comment: simplest solution: use `JOptionPane` like in `String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Name: ");` -- strongly recommended to check its [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html)

Comment: Our school have just taught C++ in my first year, but only basics. in my 2nd year they taught JAVA OOP but only basics too, now I am in my third year and they gave us a final project for our subject MOR to create a system and my group decided on that I would be the lead programmer. Its partly my fault that I didn't invest too much time in learning programming.

Comment: I have already tried JOptionPane but the problem is is popping up repeatedly and is making the game unplayable

Comment: @EhlieBendoy that's an entirely different issue. That is likely a problem in your logic

Comment: Try [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/).